# Using Metalsmith global metadata in twig templates

Tags: node.js, twig, metadata, metalsmith

I'm attempting to use Metalsmith global metadata in my twig templates.

I've not found much documentation on using global metadata in templates, regardless of templating language, other than the variable must be referenced as `global.KEY` so the following should work.

```
import metalsmith from 'metalsmith';
import twig from 'metalsmith-twig';
import path from 'path';

process.on('uncaughtException', err => console.error(err));

const siteMeta = {
    env: (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev').trim().toLowerCase(),
    site_title: 'Global Site Title'
};    

metalsmith(__dirname)
    .clean(true)
    .metadata(siteMeta)
    .source(path.resolve(__dirname, 'content'))
    .destination(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'))
    .use(twig({directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views/templates')}))
    .build(err => {if (err) throw err});
```

However, both `{{global.env}}` and `{{global.site_title}}` in my twig templates return empty strings.

Comment: I would have thought it was just `env` or `site_title` why are you prefixing them with `global.`?

Comment: see the metalsmith static stie example https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith/blob/master/examples/static-site/